# смысл переопределений основных типов

Tags: c++

Давно интересует простейший вопрос, вот есть основные типы данных char, int, float, bool, для чего в библиотеке "windows.h" куча переопределений типа INT, CHAR, FLOAT и т.д., я конечно понимаю переопределения типа DWORD, size_t и т.д., да это экономит код, но вот для чего нужно вышеперечисленные переопределения? Может они нужны для акцентирования внимания на чем-либо? Пожалуйста разъясните этот простой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Так Микрософт может обеспечить неизменность размера этих типов вне зависимости от процессора и компилятора. В случае изменения платформы можно просто поменять один заголовочный файл, а не перелопачивать гору кода.

Comment: Добавлю что это ещё для поддержания единого стиля именования типов данных - в WinAPI все типы данных пишутся исключительно в верхнем регистре.